# Transition between difference force 'center' in d3 v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js, window-resize

When I resize my window, I start a 'resize' event which will do:

```
var width = +container.clientWidth;
var height = +container.clientHeight;
simulation.force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));
simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
```

to center my node-link diagram into the middle of the canvas.
This works fine, but I don't get a transition towards the center, but an immediate jump instead.

I would like to have an animation such as seen in this example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/3355967/

However, in d3 v4 I don't know how to make this transition happen. Do I have to use a different force or can I enforce the 'transition'? Where would I have to declare it?

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/n4m1r8nb/157/ (it is positioned top left corner in the beginning and when you resize, it will 'jump' to the center')

It seems like this has been done in d3 v3 via:

```
force.size([width, height]).resume();
```

However, this method is no longer available in v4 and replaced with forceCenter (or forceX, forceY).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it by setting up a `transition`:

```js
var nodes = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "server 1"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "server 2"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "server 3"
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "name": "server 4"
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "name": "server 5"
}, {
  "id": 6,
  "name": "server 6"
}, {
  "id": 7,
  "name": "server 7"
}, {
  "id": 8,
  "name": "server 8"
}, {
  "id": 9,
  "name": "server 9"
}]

var links = [{
  source: 1,
  target: 2
}, {
  source: 1,
  target: 3
}, {
  source: 1,
  target: 4
}, {
  source: 2,
  target: 5
}, {
  source: 2,
  target: 6
}, {
  source: 3,
  target: 7
}, {
  source: 5,
  target: 8
}, {
  source: 6,
  target: 9
}, ]

var index = 10;
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  width = document.getElementById('container').clientWidth,
  height = document.getElementById('container').clientHeight,
  node,
  link;

d3.select(window).on('resize', function() {
  var w = document.getElementById('container').clientWidth;
  var h = document.getElementById('container').clientHeight;

  d3.select({}).transition().delay(500)
    .tween("center.move", function() {
        var i = d3.interpolateArray([width/2, height/2],[w/2,h/2]);
        width = w; height = h;
      return function(t) {
       var c = i(t);
        simulation.force('center', d3.forceCenter(c[0], c[1]));
        simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
      };
    });  
});


var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
    return d.id;
  }))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

update();

function update() {
  link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    })

  link = link.enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "link");

  node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id;
    })

  node = node.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node");

  node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 2.5)

  simulation
    .nodes(nodes)
    .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
    .links(links);
}

function ticked() {
  link
    .attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    });

  node
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")";
    });
}
```

```css
.link {
  stroke: #aaa;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.node {
  pointer-events: all;
  stroke: none;
  stroke-width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <svg></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought there might be an easier solution than to interpolate yourself, but this is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

For an immediate transition (and a much easier alternative than tweening),  simply remove the current force dictating the center, then create a new one:

e.g.

```
d3.select(window).on('resize', function() {
    let w = document.getElementById('container').clientWidth;
    let  h = document.getElementById('container').clientHeight;

    simulation.force("center", null)
        simulation.force('center', d3.forceCenter(w / 2, h / 2));
});
```

If you're looking for a smooth transition (as with the tweening), just center our nodes using `.force('x', ...)` and `.force('y', ...)` instead of `.force('center', ...)` in the above.